# Need for understanding in Oracle with NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS

Tags: oracle, character-encoding

I create DataBase and table in Oracle 12c with :

```
CREATE TABLE t
(a VARCHAR2(14 CHAR))
```

If I try to put : MARIE-THÉRÈSE

```
INSERT INTO t (a) values ('MARIE-THÉRÈSE');

ERROR at line 1:
ORA-12899: value too large for column "T"."A" (actual: 15, maximum:
14)
```

Some information :

```
    SQL> SELECT LENGTH('MARIE-THÉRÈSE') "Length in characters" FROM DUAL;

Length in characters
--------------------
                  15
SQL> SELECT LENGTHB ('MARIE-THÉRÈSE') "Length in bytes" FROM DUAL;

Length in bytes
---------------
             23
SELECT *
   FROM nls_database_parameters
   WHERE parameter = 'NLS_CHARACTERSET';

PARAMETER                      VALUE
------------------------------ --------------------
NLS_CHARACTERSET               AL32UTF8

SELECT value FROM NLS_DATABASE_PARAMETER
WHERE parameter='NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS';

VALUE
-----------------------------------
BYTE
```

How it will be possible to put 'MARIE-THÉRÈSE' in this column VARCHAR2(14 CHAR) without modified this column but only oracle parameters ?

Comment: Each accented characters are being counted as two characters. `SQL> select length('È') from dual;

LENGTH('??')
------------
    2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is :

```
VARCHAR2(20) : Uses the default length semantics defined by the NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS parameter which defaults to BYTE.
VARCHAR2(20 BYTE) : Allows only the specified number of bytes to be stored in the column, regardless of how many characters this represents.
VARCHAR2(20 CHAR) : Allows the specified number of characters to be stored in the column regardless of the number of bytes this equates to.

SQL> CREATE TABLE tab2 (
  2    id           NUMBER(10),
  3    description  VARCHAR2(20 CHAR)
  4  );
Table created.

SQL> DESC tab2
 Name                                                  Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------------------- -------- -----------------
 ID                                                             NUMBER(10)
 DESCRIPTION                                                    VARCHAR2(20 CHAR)
```

The default character semantics of the database or session can be altered using the NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS parameter.

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS=CHAR;
ALTER SYSTEM SET NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS=BYTE;

ALTER SESSION SET NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS=CHAR;
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS=BYTE;
```

If we alter the sessions length semantics to character and describe the tables we can see the change has taken affect by the way the column definitions are displayed.

```
SQL> ALTER SESSION SET NLS_LENGTH_SEMANTICS=CHAR;

Session altered.

SQL> desc tab1
 Name                                                  Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------------------- -------- -----------------
 ID                                                             NUMBER(10)
 DESCRIPTION                                                    VARCHAR2(20 BYTE)

SQL> DESC tab2
 Name                                                  Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------------------- -------- -----------------
 ID                                                             NUMBER(10)
 DESCRIPTION                                                    VARCHAR2(20)

SQL>
```

The INSTR, LENGTH and SUBSTR functions always deal with characters, regardless of column definitions and the character sets. For times when you specifically need to deal in bytes Oracle provides the INSTRB, LENGTHB and SUBSTRB functions.

Answer (score 1):

The LENGTH SEMANTICS parameter defines what is used by default, if you do not specify it in your DDL. For example, if you say

```
CREATE TABLE T
( a VARCHAR2(14) )
```

then the LENGTH SEMANTICS parameter will determine if column A is 14 BYTES or 14 CHARACTERS.

So in you example, you have a 15 character string, so you cannot insert it into a 14 character column, regardless of the length semantics; you will need to modify the column definition.

```
ALTER TABLE T
MODIFY a VARCHAR2(15 CHAR)
```

Comment: The string 'MARIE-THÉRÈSE' is 13 Characters and not 15. What I have to do if I don't want to modify the Column length to insert this string in 14 length?

Comment: @cobaltl. If I cop your string into a hex editor, i get the following: 4D 41 52 49 45 2D 54 48 C3 89 52 C3 88 53 45. So my Oracle and my hex editor thinks it's 15 characters. So the answer has not changed; there is nothing you can do if you do not what to change the length. Why are you so reluctant to?

Comment: All the data come from an old AS400 where column are fix length. I have to extract hundreds of tables to send then to Oracle using Java program and sqlloader. This done in one shot for migration purpose. To be able to create the table in oracle I extract the table Structure from AS400 and for this example the column lenth is 14 in AS400